# Comment « ainsi » pourrait-il résulter du sens de « avant, auparavant » ?

Tags: étymologie

Le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/ainsi) (que je cite) et  le [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ainsi) proposent trois hypothèses pour l'étymologie de « ainsi », mais cette question ne concerne que celle-ci:

> Le second élément du mot est issu du lat. *sic* « ainsi », l'orig. du 1er élément est controversée : [...]
>    Haberl, loc. cit. (et à sa suite Dauzat 1968) préfère rétablir *ainz si* dont le développement aurait été « avant ainsi », puis « à vrai dire ainsi » d'où « mais ainsi », enfin « et ainsi », hyp. qui ne peut rendre compte des anc. formes en *en-.*   [...]

Pourriez-vous expliciter le développement sémantique ci-dessus ? Je ne comprends pas l'influence et la signification de « avant », car « ainsi » est anaphorique, en référant à la conséquence ou à l'antécédent (et non pas à ce qui vient avant, comme la cause ou le référent).

Comment: une antécédent vient AVANT. Ainsi, je l'explique.

Answer (score 2):

Peut-être aller au-delà de la linguistique et de la grammaire pour aborder la philologie qui les contient :

> S'il en est ***ainsi*** maintenant, c'est qu'il s'est passé *ceci **avant***.